# telebot - удалить все сообщения бота в чате с юзером

Tags: telebot

Казалось бы задача элементарная, но вменяемого ответа так и не нашел.
Нашлись только костыли, с записью всех айдишников сообщений бота, при их отправке и последующем их удалении по id.
Но что, если в чате с юзером, от бота уже есть сообщения, которые мы не отследили? Как определить их айди и удалить?

Comment: Никак. Скажу больше - на удаление есть 24 часа